# PNI Digital Compass Driver

Tags: ros, hardware

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've recently acquired a [PNI Fieldforce TCM-XB](http://www.pnicorp.com/products/fieldforce-tcm) and would like to interface it with ROS. It communicates over serial using a binary protocol described in their datasheet. The protocol appears to be proprietary, but I am not familiar enough with the protocols used by other manufacturers to know for sure.

Basic searches in the ROS package database haven't turned up any existing packages. Before I take the time to write one, has anyone else written a ROS node for communicating with this compass?

**Update:** It's not completely polished, but here is the [fieldforce_tcm](https://github.com/mkoval/FieldforceTCM) node that I wrote. It is written in Python and publishes a `nav_msgs/Imu` message with the `orientation` field populated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10546/pni-digital-compass-driver/) by [mkoval](https://answers.ros.org/users/309/mkoval/) on ROS Answers with karma: 524 on 2011-07-09

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of any PNI drivers.  We would have had one for you, but I wrote that one for our custom FPGA solution.  ;)  No getting that one out.

It shouldn't be too difficult to write using [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) or [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/serial_ports.html).  If you remember to make it generic for all their compasses, and reconfigurable (maybe even with [dynamic reconfigure](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure)), you would make it very valuable to the community.

PS: my suggestion on an output message would be a [geometry_msgs/QuaternionStamped](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/QuaternionStamped.html).  Our compass also output pitch and roll, although not filtered, so this message type could output all of those values at once.

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2011-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mkoval](https://answers.ros.org/users/309/mkoval/) on 2011-07-10**:
Thanks for your response and the advice. We'll definitely release it to the community once it's working.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the new and latest version I have timeout problems with my PNI Prime. I also has a 0.5s timeout for almost all commands, but it seems to be actually more. This is the exception raised:

```
 File "pni_prime_imu.py", line 331, in <module>
    main()
  File "pni_prime_imu.py", line 327, in main
    raise e
pni_dev.TimeoutException: Did not recv frame_id (5,) within time limit.
```

Plesase, note that I've only changed the name of the driver to pni_dev, and create my own wrapper on top of it. Everything is the same. I increase the timeout to 1s in a >24h experiment, but at some point it wasn't enough.

Do you have any idea that could explain this behaviour?

Thanks in advance,
Enrique

---

Originally posted by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) with karma: 834 on 2012-05-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cody](https://answers.ros.org/users/1588/cody/) on 2012-05-02**:
Hi, I'm not seeing a correspondence between the line numbers you've posted here and the ones in fieldforce_tcm/src/fieldforce_tcm.py (@ commit b3c270b ).Is pni_prime_imu.py a different file currently in the fieldforce_tcm package? Are there any edits to it? Is there any more to this exception?

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2012-05-02**:
Well, this pni_prime_imu.py file is mine, just  a wrapper over the driver fieldforce_tcm.py. Let's say it's an equivalent to compass.py. However, the problem is simply the fact that the timeout expires before something arrives. I set it to 1s, instead of 0.5s. This happens in recv.

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2012-05-02**:
I also have to say, that in this particular case of a >24h experiment, I run out of batteries, so that was the reason because the sensor didn't reply any longer. Anyway, please note the fact that I increased the timeout from 0.5s to 1s. That's what I don't understand. Do you have similar problems?

**Comment by [Cody](https://answers.ros.org/users/1588/cody/) on 2012-05-03**:
I can't do anything about the battery life :) . I have however written some code in the ros node that attempts to restart the compass if a timeout in data occurs (and increased the timeout). It'll be pushed to the main repo as soon as we test it (for now, it is in github.com/jmesmon/fieldforce_tcm).

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2012-05-03**:
Sure ;) Thanks. Actually, those two things can be done: increase timeout, catch exception and retry. Anyway, it seems strange the documentation says only 0.5s, when it happens to be far more.

**Comment by [Cody](https://answers.ros.org/users/1588/cody/) on 2012-05-11**:
We've updated the driver with the code which attempts to reset it.